# Access remote Windows registry with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, remote-registry

I'm working in a Windows environment and wanting to access the registry on a remote machine using Ruby. I can't find any examples of this or the equivalent Win32 calls used in C#. Does anyone have experience with this? Is this even possible? Thank you!

Comment: In the meantime what I've done as a workaround is to create a REST/JSON web service in C# that I can call. Not the best solution, but one that unblocks me for now.